# Can I use SAML if I am using .NET Core Web API and an external frontend (hosted on a different server)?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

My setup:

- ASP.NET Core 6 Web API
- Vue frontend consuming that Web API

Reading up on how it works I think the answer to this is a no + every example of SAML implementation I've seen is for an ASP.NET Core MVC web app.

Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: The answer 's not, no. I did it for MVC + we have it with non-MVC .Net standard webforms. It doesn't need to be .Net either. Could be any other language.

Comment: Any idea or material guiding me to do this with .NetCore WebAPI?

Comment: I don't know anything specifically for .Net core. Just search for SAML 2.0 documentation.

Comment: I've obviously done that hence why im here - last resort :)

Comment: OK sorry, I at least wanted to say it is not MVC bound.

Comment: But my question is about .Net Core WebAPI + external front end (2 different servers) so you haven't really told me what I need to know at all. You told me that you can do it on same host which is not the same setup I have laid out.

Comment: NuGet.org has lots of SAML2-related packages. Which of those might work best for you is hard to say, it may depend on the server (SAML host) you'll be talking to, and will require some experimentation. We've done it with .NET Core 3 (now .NET 6) + a React frontend, which we wrote from scratch. Vue will be just as well suitable. We do Frontend-to-Backend-auth with JWT after the SAML part has finished.

Comment: Amazing thank you, glad I'm wrong! By SAML host, do you mean something like Azure Registration? @PeterB

Comment: You can host your own SAML server, but that usually only makes sense if you want multiple applications that all have the same users in a central system. SAML can also be hosted externally, e.g. in Azure AD or OpenAM. If it's for a single app and also there is no external user management solution (Single Sign On) then it is better to forget about trying to create a SAML host (because then you would have 2 problems instead of 1).

Comment: @PeterB can you elaborate on "Frontend-to-Backend-auth with JWT after the SAML part has finished." I have currently got it all hooked up so that you call the backend login - it does the challenge and allows you to sign in with MS - then it redirects back to my api with the cookie data. This is the problem - how on earth can I get to front end? I have tried changing the returnUrl to the front end but you get nothing

Comment: SAML will identify the user for you by giving you e.g. their email address. You can then put that as a Claim in a JWT token, along with other info like a Role ("User" or "Admin"). The Role value can be used as an 'access filter' in .NET by using [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] on protected Action Methods. This is not the place to teach you all about JWT, for that there are many resources, both online and offline, both free and paid.

Comment: @PeterB I wasn't clear enough, so what I'm getting at is you get redirected back to your api after the login from microsoft, how is this then relayed to the front end?

Comment: You would host your JavaScript app inside an asp.net site. You cannot be redirected back to the api from the IDP.

Comment: @cederlof yea I ended up using OIDC and did it in the JS front end since combining BE & FE wasn't an option